# Multiple implementation of custom uitableviewcell using dynamic prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Three different, dynamic prototype tableviewcells are used in my project.

Two are stock cells(basic with different options), and one is a custom cell. And this, may change as required.

The problem I face is while dequeuing the cells.

If they are done normally as UITableViewCells, I'm not able to use my custom cell outlets or actions.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

And, If they are done the other way, the app crashes with the below error.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
```

Error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x38595c58) to 'AppName.SwitchTableViewCell' (0x13cdf8).
```

Below is the implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate Methods

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Setup a cellIdentifer string to store the cell reuse identifier you want to use for each row.
    var cellIdentifier: String

    // Switch through each row and set the appropriate cell reuse identifier
    switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {
    case .AudioDevices, .Acknowledgments:
        cellIdentifier = "DisclosureCell"
    case .AllowNotifications, .ShowCloudMusic:
        cellIdentifier = "SwitchCell"
    case .Version:
        cellIdentifier = "RightDetailCell"
    }

    // Populate your cell reuse identifier into the cell

    if cellIdentifier == "SwitchCell" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    // Switch through each cell, and implement the labels/setup for each row
    // The order of the cases is irrelevant!
    switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {
    case .AudioDevices:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Audio Devices"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(userDefaults.integerForKey(audioDeviceListKey))
    case .AllowNotifications:
        cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Allow Notifications"
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
    case .ShowCloudMusic:
        cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Show Cloud Music"
    case .Acknowledgments:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Acknowledgements"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    case .Version:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Version"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = buildVersion
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    // Return the cell
    return cell
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "Two or stock, ", what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry typo, Two are basic cells with slight variation and the other is a custom one..

Comment: have you registered your custom cell? tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

Comment: Sorry i don't get your question please clarify this upload a screen shot of your screen in your question so we easily understand your question..

Comment: show your full `cellForRowAtI......` code

Comment: Yes, it has been done. Is there a way that I can switch between these two? `UITableViewCell` vs `SwitchTableViewCell`

Comment: @Shyam you no need to outlet you can use tag to access the button or labels etc.

Comment: Is the class of the appropriate cell set to `SwitchTableViewCell` in Interface Builder?

Comment: @vadian, Yes...

Comment: @balkaransingh, will I be able to access the label's properties, by using only tags? I'm not exactly sure, about this..

Comment: just remove two line that you return in if cellIdentifier == "SwitchCell" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }   remove return cell in if condition your error gone,

Comment: @Shyam check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Use Default separator .]

To use multiple kinds of cell in Table View, you have to put some condition to check to see which cell be used for certain condition.

```
func tableView cellForRowAtInd....... {
    //depends on what base you separate both cells 
    if condition = true { 
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
       return cell
    }

}
```

Update based upon your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

You are already returning before cell before your other part of code run. Hence the cell is already returned and its of no use for other part of code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Setup a cellIdentifer string to store the cell reuse identifier you want to use for each row.
    var cellIdentifier: String

    // Switch through each row and set the appropriate cell reuse identifier
    switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {
    case .AudioDevices, .Acknowledgments:
        cellIdentifier = "DisclosureCell"
    case .AllowNotifications, .ShowCloudMusic:
        cellIdentifier = "SwitchCell"
    case .Version:
        cellIdentifier = "RightDetailCell"
    }

    // Populate your cell reuse identifier into the cell

    if cellIdentifier == "SwitchCell" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell

        // Switch through each cell, and implement the labels/setup for each row
        // The order of the cases is irrelevant!
        switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {
        case .AudioDevices:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Audio Devices"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(userDefaults.integerForKey(audioDeviceListKey))
        case .AllowNotifications:
            cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Allow Notifications"
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        case .ShowCloudMusic:
            cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Show Cloud Music"
        case .Acknowledgments:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Acknowledgements"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        case .Version:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Version"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = buildVersion
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        // Return the cell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Switch through each cell, and implement the labels/setup for each row
        // The order of the cases is irrelevant!
        switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {
        case .AudioDevices:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Audio Devices"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(userDefaults.integerForKey(audioDeviceListKey))
        case .AllowNotifications:
            cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Allow Notifications"
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        case .ShowCloudMusic:
            cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Show Cloud Music"
        case .Acknowledgments:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Acknowledgements"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        case .Version:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Version"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = buildVersion
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        // Return the cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: show your celForRowAtIndexPath code and a screenshot of you view controller.

Comment: Added as requested

Comment: Should I have all the cases in both or only the relevant ones?

Comment: Why you return cell 2 time in one condition ?

Comment: @Shyam its ok brother

Comment: @Mr.UB. On a separate note, how do I grey out a cell? (as in to show, that it is disabled)

Comment: just change the bg color of the cell or any other visual effect based upon enable/disable condition.

Comment: @Shyam i have update this answer but wait for Mr.UB response

Answer (score 0):

plz use this

```
   if cellIdentifier == "SwitchCell" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```

access the label with tag like this in that cell where yon not define outlets

```
if let theLabel = self.view.viewWithTag(123) as? UILabel {
        theLabel.text = "some text"
    }
```

Comment: @Shyam my pleasure.